# Various timeouts in loops

Tags: python, loops

I have 2 loops in Python (1st checking time, 2nd making some functions depending on the time values). I need to check the time once in hour or more and 1 sec delay in each loop of the second loop.

I tried something like this:

```
while True:
  dt=datetime.now()
  time.sleep(3600)
  while True:
    print("Current time: ", dt)
    time.sleep(1)
```

But of course in this case second loop cant run before sleep time ends and it will be looped on the second loop forever

How can i split them?

I mean, i need "Current time:" print every second, but dt update every hour

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask].

Comment: Thank you, guys so much! Ashish’s answer is easier for me )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
sec = 1
while True:
  if sec%3600 == 0:
      dt=datetime.now()
  print("Current time: ", datetime.now())
  time.sleep(1)
  sec += 1
```

This will print current time every second, and will update your `dt` every 3600 sec (i.e, 1hr)

Comment: The code before/after `sleep(1)` takes time, so it will not print each second. You have to `ts = time.time()`, `sleep(ts + 1 - time.time())` and `ts = ts + 1`, and protect the code from sleeping forever (ts + 1 < time.time()).

Answer (score 0):

A fixed up version of your code (untested).

```
seconds = 0  # or 1 to not do hourly action immediately
while True:
    if not seconds:
        dt=datetime.now()  # every hour action
    print(dt)  # every second action
    seconds = (seconds + 1) % 3600 
    time.sleep(1)
```

Since time.sleep is guaranteed to sleep a minimum of the time specified, with no maximum, the interval between hourly actions will likely be longer than an hour.  To be more accurate, you could check the time more often and advance the seconds counter accordingly.